# How to authorize a connection to a CRM?

Tags: authorization, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm at a computer where I'm not allowed to use the helper classes from SDK. I thought that if I have the following information specified, I could still connect but [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh670628.aspx) confused me and scared me to death.

```
string organization = @"https://serverName/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc";
string name = "myUserName";
string pass = "1234";

ClientCredentials cred = new ClientCredentials();
cred.UserName.UserName = name;
cred.UserName.Password = pass;
```

Then I get stuck. I don't get the usual *OrganizationServiceProxy*. In fact, I'm not clear on how to obtain a reference to the service at all!

How do I do that?

The targeted system will be authorizing my user via AD (on-premise) and O365 account/live id (on-line).

Answer (score 0):

The following link show how to get a refrence to the Organization Service Proxy

[Organization Service PRoxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx)

and you can find a sample for it at the following path

"SDK/SampleCode\CS\GeneralProgramming\LateBound\CRUDOperationsDE.cs"

Comment: Not really getting the flow. They use a lot of helper classes and the execution is all over the place. I'd like to **learn** how to do it. No proxies, helpers and such... I have an URL, a user name and a password. What do I do with it?! I know I'm supposed to use *ClientCredentials* but that's about all I got.